# Configure Azure WebApp to read secrets from Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I am attempting to implement Azure Key Vault in my API. Inside my key vault is a secret key. I have made code changes to get the secret key from the key vault. Locally my user has permission to access this so it gets when requested. Within my staging environment I have not been able to get the permissions for the webapp correct.

I have followed the guidelines on (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/tutorial-net-create-vault-azure-web-app) without success. These steps did not work.

I have also gone into my webapp under the Portal > navigated to WebApp > Settings > Identity and added a Azure role of Key Vaults Secrets User to the Azure Key Vault resource. This also did not work.

What configuration is required so that when I deploy these code changes it will actually have the permissions needed to get the secret key from the key vault?

Here is the code I am using to access my secret:

```
var client = new SecretClient(vaultUri: new Uri("key-vault-uri"), credential: new DefaultAzureCredential());
KeyVaultSecret secret = client.GetSecret("secret-key-id");
var key = secret.Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Refer this SOThread [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77599618/19648279) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75565115/19648279) for access policies and permission

Comment: Receiving this error in an environment, what additional do I need to configure? 
System.AggregateException: Retry failed after 4 tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry or by configuring a custom retry policy in ClientOptions.RetryPolicy. (An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (IP_ADDRESS))

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using a user-assigned managed identity.
If so, you need an application setting key of AZURE_CLIENT_ID with the value being the client id of your managed identity.

Also, go to the "Access Policies" of your Key Vault. Create a new policy for your managed identity with the secret permissions you require.

Comment: Is the client id the principal id?

Comment: It is not the principal id. It is the "Client ID" as shown on the overview page of your managed identity.

Comment: I'm not sure where to find what you're referring to in the portal.

Comment: go to your identity's resource page. the first tab is the overview page. Here you will find the Client ID.

Comment: Does not work. I created a managed identity, added to it the role of "Key Vault Secret User" to the key vault resource. Went to Access policy within the key vault and added the new managed identity to it with get, list permissions on the secret. Now even locally it does not work. Gives me "ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple attempts failed to obtain a token from the managed identity endpoint." error

Comment: For reference, passing the client ID in the following way:
```
            DefaultAzureCredential credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
{
     ManagedIdentityClientId = "GUID"
});
```